# Variables not holding json data in angular2

Tags: angular

So it's a weird issue that I have not been able to trouble shoot, I imagine part of it has to do with me not knowing async calls in angular but here we go!

I am retrieving the json data I want, but my variables are not grabbing it and I am completely lost as to why.

Here is my **edit_role.component**

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
import { CORE_DIRECTIVES } from 'angular2/common';
import {RoleService} from './../services/roles.services';
import {OnInit} from 'angular2/core';
import {Http, HTTP_PROVIDERS} from 'angular2/http';
import {RouteParams, RouterLink} from 'angular2/router';


@Component({
  selector: 'edit_role',
  providers: [RoleService],
  directives: [CORE_DIRECTIVES],
  templateUrl: 'app/roles/edit_role.html'
})
export class RoleEdit implements OnInit{

    role: any;
    modules: any;
    new_modules: any;
    params: any;

    constructor(private _roleService: RoleService, params:RouteParams){
        this.params = params.get('id');
    };

    ngOnInit(){
        this.getEditRoles(this.params);
    };

    getEditRoles(id){
        this._roleService.getEditRoles(id).subscribe(role_edit =>
            //console.log(role_edit.data[0])
            {this.role = role_edit.data[0],
            this.modules = role_edit.modules[0],
            this.new_modules = role_edit.new_modules[0]}
        );
    };
}
```

my **role.services** is:

```
import {Injectable} from 'angular2/core';
import {Http, HTTP_PROVIDERS} from 'angular2/http';
import 'rxjs/Rx';

@Injectable()
export class RoleService {

    constructor(public http: Http) { 
    }

    getEditRoles(id){
        return this.http.get('http://localhost:3000/api/roles/edit/' +id)
            .map((response => response.json()))
    }
}
```

my **edit_role.html** template

```
<div class="page-data">
    <form method="post" action="api/roles/edit/{{role.ID}}" name="{{role.ID}}">

        <table cellpadding="11">
            <tr>
                <div class="label"> Role Name </div>
                    <input type="text" name="role_name" value={{role.ROLE_NAME}}>

                <div class="label"> Description</div>
                    <input type="text" name="description" value={{role.DESCRIPTION}}>

                <div class="label"> Active Record </div>
                <div *ngIf="role.ACTIVE_FLAG === 'Y'">
                    <input type="radio" name="active_flag" value="Y" checked> Active
                    <input type="radio" name="active_flag" value="N"> Inactive
                </div>
                <div *ngIf="role.ACTIVE_FLAG === 'N'">
                    <input type="radio" name="active_flag" value = "Y"> Active
                    <input type="radio" name="active_flag" value= "N" checked> Inactive
                </div>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
</div>
```

This is the only html I am testing atm so it's not using modules/new_modules
my **error**

> Cannot read property 'ID' of undefined in [api/roles/edit/{{role.ID}} in RoleEdit@1:21]

My **data**

```
{
new_modules: [
  {
    MODULE_NAME: "user_roles"
  }
],
modules: [
  {
    ROLE_ID: 6,
    MODULE_NAME: "roles",
    INSERT_ALLOWED_FLAG: "Y",
    UPDATE_ALLOWED_FLAG: "N",
    DELETE_ALLOWED_FLAG: "N",
    QUERY_ONLY: "Y"
  },
  {
    ROLE_ID: 6,
    MODULE_NAME: "test_mod",
    INSERT_ALLOWED_FLAG: "Y",
    UPDATE_ALLOWED_FLAG: "N",
    DELETE_ALLOWED_FLAG: "N",
    QUERY_ONLY: "N"
  },
  {
    ROLE_ID: 6,
    MODULE_NAME: "users",
    INSERT_ALLOWED_FLAG: "Y",
    UPDATE_ALLOWED_FLAG: "Y",
    DELETE_ALLOWED_FLAG: "Y",
    QUERY_ONLY: "Y"
  }
],
data: [
  {
    ID: 6,
    ROLE_NAME: "Fire",
    DESCRIPTION: "Something hot",
    ACTIVE_FLAG: "Y"
  }
 ]
}
```

I know this error is caused by the fact that **my roles, modules, and new_modules** are not receiving any data.  The weird part is, when I do console.log(role_edit.data[0]) it retrieves my json data.

So I have 2 problems I think, one is that my HTML loads before my request is received which crashes my html before load.  The other part is, that even though I can console.log my data I can't actually store it in a variable.

Comment: Am I missing something or doesn't `response.json().data` fix this?

Comment: @ToddWCrone so there are a couple issues with just doing that, first off .data would only send me my info at the very bottom of my json string in the data section.  I would not get modules or new_modules, the other issue being that my html loads and crashes before my server responds with my data.  Hence why SnareChops fixed my issues with the ? marks in my html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angular 2 expects all bound properties to not be undefined. In your case `role` is undefined at first, and then gets loaded in after. Thankfully the Angular team has thought of this and has introduced a syntax that will help with this.

example:

```
{{role?.ID}}
```

This will prevent the error from occurring and will simply display nothing, until role *is* defined and then it will display the value of `ID`

Therefore this HTML should solve the issue you are having

```
<form method="post" action="api/roles/edit/{{role?.ID}}" name="{{role?.ID}}">
    <table cellpadding="11">
        <tr>
            <div class="label"> Role Name </div>
                <input type="text" name="role_name" value={{role?.ROLE_NAME}}>

            <div class="label"> Description</div>
                <input type="text" name="description" value={{role?.DESCRIPTION}}>

            <div class="label"> Active Record </div>
            <div *ngIf="role?.ACTIVE_FLAG === 'Y'">
                <input type="radio" name="active_flag" value="Y" checked> Active
                <input type="radio" name="active_flag" value="N"> Inactive
            </div>
            <div *ngIf="role?.ACTIVE_FLAG === 'N'">
                <input type="radio" name="active_flag" value = "Y"> Active
                <input type="radio" name="active_flag" value= "N" checked> Inactive
            </div>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you so much!  I can't believe it was as simple as that.

Comment: Happy to help! If this solved the question for you, then please be sure to accept this answer to help other future searchers identify the solution that worked for you.

Comment: Not sure if I should start yet another thread, I should've probably added this in, but now I have an `<option *ngFor="#module of modules" value = "{{module?.MODULE_NAME}}">{{module?.MODULE_NAME}}</option>` but since it's a ngFor I assume I am putting all of the question marks in the wrong areas.

Comment: That should work, and I don't think that the question mark is even needed in this case, since it's under an `*ngFor`. But yes, if you're having a different issue, then it's best to post it as a new question.

Comment: Ok thanks!  Yeah it's not working I'm going to cruise the net for a while longer to see if I can solve it, I really appreciate your help!